Simple IIF statement in Access has invalid syntax error
I'm getting a syntax error with Access IIF statement:
IIf( [GroupSize] > 0,"Yes","No")

I don't see an error in the syntax, there's the statement to check, and then Yes and No. The GroupSize term is in my query I'm adding the statement to.
I've also tried, but it still says syntax error
IIf( [GroupSize] > 0, Yes, No)
IIf( [GroupSize] > 0, 'Yes', 'No')
IIf( [GroupSize] = 0,"No","Yes")
IIf( [GroupSize] > 0,-1,0)


IIf is not a statement, but a function. What is the larger context where you have this expression? Can you provide the whole query? You probably placed this IIf somewhere where it wasn't syntactically allowed.

is the [GroupSize] a numerical value or a text value? Try for instance > "0", see what happens.

I was using it in the builder option for a query (in design view) not in the SQL view. GroupSize is a numerical value

Use it like this:
Select *, IIf([GroupSize] = 0,"No","Yes") As GroupSizeCheck
From YourTable

